# Avoid facebook from pulling og meta tags data/or scraping from webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I have a requirement of posting feed on facebook with information such as description,name,title,picture and link and when user clicks on posted feed he should redirected to **link** url. what my  issue is it showing different feed on fb actually what is does is it pulls og meta data from  link url instead of custom data provided by me.This is what I have done so far:

```
Calling REST API:-https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?description=This is desc&name=xyz&picture=imageurl&link=https://play.google.com/store/search?q=Subway%20Surfers&c=apps&hl=en&display=popup&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8000/&app_id=xyz.
```

Answer (score 0):

Open Graph(og) Markup is the standard that they use to fetch the data. Please read through the documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters) which explains it clearly.

Hope it helps!